# Class hierarchy diagram for abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can anyone direct me to a diagram of abstract algebraic structures (monoids, groups, ..) arranged like an object-oriented class hierarchy? I am used to thinking about subtype relationships that way from programming.

Comment: For a start, you might try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_algebraic_structures or http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/varieties

Comment: @Ted  this is good! If you post as an answer i will accept it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you might try one of these:

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_algebraic_structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_algebraic_structures)

[math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/varieties](http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/varieties)

Note that the second one is limited to a certain subset of structures called "varieties", and therefore omits some commonly studied algebraic structures, like fields.

Comment: I didn't realize there were so many ways to organize these structures. This is very helpful.